# How do I display a list of elements in the Play! Framework?

Tags: html-lists, playframework-1.x

I have a list of elements that I pass as an argument into the `render` method. I have no experience in HTML though and was wondering how I'd print all elements in the list?

Comment: specify Play framework version, best by adding propper tag: `playframework-1.x` or `playframework-2.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if using play 1.2.x with Groovy templates:

```
<ul>
  #{list items:myList, as:'element'}
    <li>${element.name}</li>
  #{/list}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using playframework 1.x

if you call render(myElements) from your controller, an myElements is a list of strings, it will look something like this in your view.

```
...
<ul>
  #{list myElements, as:'elem'}
    <li>&{elem}</li>
  #{/list}
</ul>
...
```

I will advice you to read the [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/home) on playframework.org. It is really good and easy to read. You will probably learn a lot. If you want to learn html, I think [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com/) is a good starting point.